# How to call sendEvent() from webdriver?

Tags: webdriver, phantomjs, casperjs

We have a Python script which uses webdriver and PhantomJS to perform some tests. However, we'd like to send direct QT events using sendEvent() function (this is possible from both phantomJS scripting and casperJS).

I didn't find any docs for webdriver, though. How to perform such an action?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `sendEvent()` a JS function?

Comment: @nilesh yes. This is a function used in phantomJS scripts and in casperJS ones. Also this is the name of the C(++) function in the sources of the phantomjs itself.